# System Paths and Modules

Tags: python, directory, filesystems, package, python-module

I have the following setup:

```
/project/
    /api/
        __init__.py
        test.py
    /modules/
        __init__.py
        api.py
```

I am trying to, from the /project/ directory, run api.py: `python modules/api.py`

The api module attempts to import the test module from the api package, but fails.  I have tried the following:

```
import api.test
import project.api.test  # (with an __init__.py in my /project/ directory)
```

I have even attempted to add the api package's parent directory to the system path as described:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

#### Question

How can I set up my project in such a way that each package has knowledge of other packages in it's parent directory, which is also the project's root directory?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to recursively add all directories to the system path? api.py is in a sub-directory. Why are you using `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(..))`? Just picking on the logic. I haven't used `os.path.dirname` before

Comment: The logic is I want the directory of the file itself, then I want the directory of that directory.  It is equivalent for asking for a file's parent directory :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a `project/modules/api.py` **file** as well as a `projects/api` **directory** with an `__init__.py` file in it - you're getting descriptor collisions. Rename one of them to something else, and your code should work:

```
/project/
    /api/
        __init__.py
        test.py
    /modules/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

Then run `python modules/foo.py` and in foo.py:

```
from ..api import test
```

or alternatively:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../api'))
import test
```

Comment: The ..api was not required.  Your original solution was best:  I renamed /module/api.py to /module/apihandler.py and it's now running.  Thank you.